# Ruby on Rails, image does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I am attempting to do some basic Rails. I am trying to load an image from the `app/assets/images` folder using the following code:

```
<%= image_tag 'image.jpg'%>
```

It generates the following address (I am using localhost:3000):
http://localhost:3000/images/image.jpg

I have attempted all of the different iterations of Rails images I could find including using `<img>` tag with `src="/assets/images/image.jpg"` etc. All with no luck.

Also attempted changing production.rb (edit: and development.rb) to have the following code:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Following the localhost, link gives an error

> "No route matches [GET] "/images/image.jpg""

Comment: If you work on localhost, why you change `production.rb` rather then `development.rb`?

Comment: @AntonTkachov I suppose that would make more sense. I'll put it down to being new to Rails. I've made that alteration but unfortunately still without success.

Comment: What version of rails do you have. `rails -v` in console

Comment: @AntonTkachov `rails -v` is 5.0.7

Comment: have you restarted the server? `rails s`

Answer (score 1):

The public path that Sprockets uses by default is /assets.
This can be changed to something else:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"
```

[from rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path)

So your image must be available at http://localhost:3000/assets/image.jpg

PS: Just as an advice, try to read the guides, that will definitely help you out in future.

Comment: When you say my image must be available at "http://localhost:3000/assets/image.jpg" does that mean that if the image has the file path app/assets/image.jpg then it should work? I have tried this but still get the same error.

Comment: No, basically, without any extra configs that you initially mentioned and image.jpg being in `app/assets/images/`  should be fine

Comment: Ah... This is where I started (after reading up on other posts). I only made other changes because this wasn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: if you are using byebug as a debugging gem put `<% byebug  %>` on you page then head to the console where server is running and try to investigate what  `image_tag 'image.jpg'` produces. the other common thing is omitting file extension in `image_tag`, or maybe putting wrong one. does your file really has jpg extension.

Comment: While I can't test exactly what you're asking right at this moment I think I can answer what the image_tag produces and that is the url: http://localhost:3000/images/image.jpg if I'm misinterpreting you feel free to wait for me to be able to check those other things you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

and add

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.quiet = true
```

to your `development.rb`

Comment: I have removed the 

`config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true`

The other ones were already there.

Comment: Reload your app (stop rails and launch it again) and check whether it works

Comment: I am now getting an error:
"TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

To solve a separate issue where I was getting an error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method) on

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

I changed the 'application' to 'default' as per someone's suggestion. It fixed the issue but it seems this change was later causing my image problems. To fix the image problems I changed it back to 'application' and then to fix this original TypeError I removed the require_tree from application.js and it worked. Here's to hoping that doesn't break something else.